# Function doesn't treat calling parameter as value in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

This is my function.

```
test_gene <- function(gene, gene_data, gene_col) 
{with(gene_data, gene_data[(get(gene_col) == gene),])
}
```

And this is call of function:

```
test_gene(gene = "CXCR4",gene_data = df, gene_col = "gene")
```

I want to filter specific genes from my data frame (tibble), but it won't work in function call. If I type it in console like this, than it works. It's like R doesn't evaluate calling parameter gene as a value. I tried filter(), also doesn't work.

```
with(df, df[(gene == "CXCR4"),])

test_gene(gene = "CXCR4",gene_data = df, gene_col = "gene")
```

```
# A tibble: 48 x 15
   sample_name gene     cp cp_plot delta_cp delta_cp_plot delta_cp_contro… delta_delta_cp     lfc    fc gene_group
   <chr>       <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>         <dbl>            <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <fct>     
 1 c1_50       CD24   31.7    31.7     8.09          8.09             8.51        -0.418   0.418  1.34  target    
 2 c1_90       CD24   32.0    32.0     8.06          8.06             8.51        -0.447   0.447  1.36  target    
 3 c2_50       CD24   32.1    32.1     8.60          8.60             8.51         0.0877 -0.0877 0.941 target    
 4 c2_90       CD24   31.2    31.2     8.62          8.62             8.51         0.110  -0.110  0.927 target    
 5 c3_50       CD24   31.6    31.6     8.61          8.61             8.51         0.105  -0.105  0.930 target    
 6 c3_90       CD24   31.8    31.8     9.07          9.07             8.51         0.563  -0.563  0.677 target    
 7 sp1_50      CD24   32.9    32.9     7.43          7.43             8.51        -1.08    1.08   2.12  target    
 8 sp1_90      CD24   34.7    34.7     7.70          7.70             8.51        -0.806   0.806  1.75  target    
 9 sp2_50      CD24   32.3    32.3     6.75          6.75             8.51        -1.76    1.76   3.39  target    
10 sp2_90      CD24   33.1    33.1     7.46          7.46             8.51        -1.05    1.05   2.07  target    
# … with 38 more rows, and 4 more variables: sample_group_code <fct>, petri_number <fct>, confluence <fct>,
#   sample_group <fct>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you provide a sample of your data and paste the exact error that was thrown?

Comment: Hi! It doesn't throw an error, it just returns data frame as nothing was typed,

Comment: Does this work inside your function: `gene_data %>% filter(!!rlang::sym(gene_col) == gene)`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work :/

Comment: I think the problem is that you have two objects called `gene`. Try renaming your `gene` argument in the function to e.g. `gene_name`, then try my previous suggestion once more... does that work?

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!! THANK YOU @crlwbm  and  THANK YOU ALL:DDD

Answer (score 2):

Your initial trial was not that far from your goal. It was just a matter of organization. the `gene` string got R confused. Consider

```
df <-structure(list(sample_name = structure(1:10, .Label = c("c1_50", 
"c1_90", "c2_50", "c2_90", "c3_50", "c3_90", "sp1_50", "sp1_90", 
"sp2_50", "sp2_90"), class = "factor"), gene = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("CD24", "CXCR4"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"))
```

I modified your data.frame slightly to make it more relevant to my point

```
test_gene <- function(gene_data, col, val) {
## Data Definition
## gene_data  . a data.frame
## col        . a string representing a column name in gene_data
## val        . a string representing a value of col in gene_data
with(gene_data, gene_data[get(col) == val,])
}
```

then

```
test_gene(col="gene",val = "CXCR4",gene_data = df)

##   sample_name  gene
## 0      sp2_90 CXCR4
```